# IE7 css styles being applied inconsistently

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

I apologize if this question has been asked before.  I am relatively new to CSS and web development.  I am developing a web app that has to target IE7. For the life of me I cannot figure out why on the "assignments" page the unordered list is formatted one way and on the "Employee Data" page it is not being formatted at all.  Both pages are using the same style sheet.  I am only having this issue in IE7 and IE8, the newer versions work fine.

Here is a link to the site

http://www.j-holmes.net/

Again, I apologize if this question has been asked before. I can't think of any more search criteria to google up an answer for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE 7 doesn't support <nav> you can replace  to a div: nav ul li a

Comment: Thanks, that was the exact problem.  I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your ul element nested within a nav element, but on the EmployeeData.aspx page it appears that the nav element is closed like in the linked image here: http://www.kruegerwebdesign.com/images/questions/closednav.png

Just make sure that nav element is open and contains your unordered list, and it should style the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why, but the `nav` element doesn't work on the employee data page. The browser thinks that there is one `nav` element before the `menu` element and one after instead of one surrounding the `menu` element. As the CSS relies on the `menu` element being in the `nav` element, it doesn't apply.

I can't see any error in the HTML code, but there may be some error that keeps the browser from parsing the code correctly.

Another possible reason could be that you are using HTML5 specific elements, which IE7 doesn't understand. It seems to work anyway in some pages, but it's a factor that may make the browser more sensetive to markup errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is HTML5 tags like  not working in an IE7 browser, I've found this file useful. It translates HTML5 for old fashioned browsers: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/ It's certainly worth a shot.